# Why does my PC freeze on boot if I have a usb flash plugged in

Tags: boot

The boot sequence is not set to boot from usb.  the screen hangs on the initial screen which I customized with a photo.   everything freezes, PC doesn't respond to any stimuli. even the power button had to be continuously pressed to turn off.  normally before windows load, the power button can turn off the PC with simple push.   when it happened in the past I thought a coincidence, but this happened again. any theory or place of fault to look for?

EDIT:

It's not a boot from USB issue, 
1. as I said from setup I already set it to boot from CD then HDD. 
2. normally if it is booting, the screen displays text and the custom screen goes away.  yes even when booting from usb.
3. the typical behavior if it doesn't find bootable usb it switches to next device or display error.  in this case it is not even set to boot from usb I mean I set it that way in the setup.   and it is crashing on the initial boot screen which is a custom photo.

My PC is a self-built desktop. quite old, core 2 duo, motherboard: GA-X38-DS4

Comment: You might consider posting the make and model of your PC in your question.

Comment: Update: I failed to mention that the USB stick is 3.0 while my motherboard doesn't support 3.0. but they should be backward compatible.  I tested on an older computer pentium 4 and it didn't freeze.  The freezing happens if plugged at anytime during setup, boot, before windows or linux load.  in conclusion it is likely a bios bug that was never fixed by manufacturer. I checked my bios version and it is the latest circa 2009.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your PC boots, the BIOS has to enumerate USB devices.  If there is a problem with this process, such as:

- Cheap flash drive doesn't quite obey the USB standard,
- Device that looks like a flash drive (such as mp3 player or picture frame) to the OS doesn't quite obey the USB standard,
- Device is actually multiple USB storage devices (some have a device that looks like a CD-ROM in addition to a device thats writable) and BIOS doesn't like it,
- Other BIOS/UEFI bugs,
- Issue with your device, such as bad firmware or other defect,
- Issue with your motherboard, USB port, or controller on motherboard,

then the BIOS could hang.

I've experienced card readers and mp3 players that cause some BIOSes to hang.  BIOS problems with booting off of anything but a floppy or the first internal hard drive are well known since the mid 90's and possibly earlier.  It *should* work properly but in reality it just may not due to a poorly programmed BIOS.

You can try updating your BIOS or UEFI firmware to see if it helps.

Comment: I feel that covers up all the possible problems.  I'll check to see if I can pin one of them.  I think no longer there are updates for my bios, perhaps support ended.  but I wanted to know what could be the issue and this helps greatly.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be a hidden functionality that miss-detects the boot signature on your flash drive as specially crafted data. If you are lucky, it may just freeze. In my case this killed the board.

I have a similar issue with the **EVGA FTW3** board. If I am inside BIOS setup, the POST screen, or the boot device select screen, then as soon as I plug in a USB stick with FreeBSD-11.1-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img, the computer freezes.

I also tried:

- connecting a USB stick with FreeBSD 11.1, or OpenBSD 5.7 installed: **still freezes**
- using a different USB stick: **still freezes**
- leaving the USB stick for more than 20 seconds: **the board powered off and died, I could no longer power on the computer**

Then I contacted the EVGA support and my board was replaced, but:

- the **new board is also affected by this freezing**, so I'm not willing to risk and kill it
- using a different computer: **works correctly, I can also boot from that USB**

Then I tried to erase the USB stick and copy Windows or Linux setup files to it:

- **works correctly, I can also boot from that USB**

EVGA FTW3 boards have a serious fault. This is not the PC trying to boot from USB, then crashing. Rather there is some hidden, undocumented functionality that is probably trying to update the BIOS or configuration if it detects a signature matching the BSD boot record. This is poorly designed since it does not check the integrity of the data, and ends up destroying the board.

I also read about MSI 975X freezing when a USB drive is present during boot:
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/47368/

Answer (score 0):

The reason it freezes is because when your PC boots, it looks for things to boot from, and eventually boots from your HDD, loading windows, etc.
What's happening is: your PC is trying to boot an OS from your USB flash, and is freezing because there's no OS to boot.

You may be able to force it to look to the HDD first by editing the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks BUT did you read what I wrote?  It is not set to boot from usb. and beside if it doesn't find an OS on a usb it usually switch to another device, if there is no other device, it should display no bootable device found.  in this case however, it is not even set to boot from USB.  and you don't enter bios using F8, on most PCs either F2 or del.  F8 is for safe mode on windows

Comment: @Dreadedsemicolon Actually this answer is likely correct. The computer is still looking for a boot device and is finding your usb drive before the hdd. If you set the hdd to first in your bios it should stop doing this. Just not having usb in your boot order list isn't enough. Sometimes you'll even experience this with other usb hardware that isn't a storage device.

Comment: The button to get into the bios is not the same for all computers. I've seen esc, delete, backspace, f2, f9, and others be the button to press. It depends on your mobo manufacturer.

Comment: @Doug Watkins,  Actually wrong as I said it is not set to boot from USB.  maybe I should've stated that I know how to enter setup and I already set my PC too boot from CD then hdd.  I'm not sure but what do you think I meant by saying it is not set to boot from USB?    yes I know setup entrance buttons are different that's why i said most.  but he said F8 which is not very typical at least should say del which is common.

Comment: beside when PC starts booting the initial custom screen goes away and displays text.  this doesn't happen.    and if it doesn't find boot on USB it would say that or switch to next device. BUT again I set it from setup to boot from CD then HDD.

Comment: @Dreadedsemicolon I'm not going to get into what button he should have said, that was the point of my last comment. As far as not having usb in the list, that is the point of my comment to you. I personally have see a computer do exactly what you said and usb is not enabled in the list. The only fix was to set boot to hdd first. Even though it wasn't  in the list it still wanted to boot to the usb. The other option was to press the right key to bring up the one time boot menu and choose hdd. I've even seen this happen with a wireless keyboard/mouse. The usb dongle caused the no boot issue.

Comment: HDD set to 2nd,  CD to first.  that's my point to you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem stopped happening in my laptop, when I disabled USB legacy support in the BIOS